При перезагрузке страницы, у меня обнуляется favorite
При перезагрузке страницы, у меня обнуляется favorite. И если стоял лайк, то он не стоит, хотя счетчик и все данные полученные из data верные
файл с ошибкой:
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useGetArticleQuery } from "../../redux/defaulApi";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import styleArticleFull from "./ArticleFull.module.scss";
import Markdown from "markdown-to-jsx";
import { Flex, Spin, Alert } from "antd";
import { LoadingOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { QuestionCircleOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Button, Popconfirm } from "antd";

export default function ArticleFull() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"));
    const [delArticle] = useArticleDeleteMutation();

    const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetArticleQuery(slug, { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true });

    const [addFavotite] = useAddFavoriteMutation();
    const [removeFavorite] = useRemoveFavoriteMutation();

    const deleteArticle = () => {
        delArticle(data?.article?.slug);
        navigate("/");
    };

    const deleteLike = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("del");
            await removeFavorite(slug);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const addLike = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("add");
            await addFavotite(slug);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    const editingPanel =
        user?.username == data?.article?.author?.username ? (
            <div className={styleArticleFull.editButtons}>
                <Popconfirm
                    onConfirm={deleteArticle}
                    title="Delete the article"
                    description="Are you sure to delete this article?"
                    icon={
                        <QuestionCircleOutlined
                            style={{
                                color: "red",
                            }}
                        />
                    }
                >
                    <Button danger>Delete</Button>
                </Popconfirm>

                <Link to={`/articles/${slug}/edit`} className={styleArticleFull.btnEdit}>
                    Edit
                </Link>
            </div>
        ) : null;

    if (error)
        return (
            <Flex justify="center">
                <Alert
                    message="There's been some kind of mistake, we're already figuring it out!"
                    type="error"
                    showIcon
                />
            </Flex>
        );
    if (isLoading)
        return (
            <Flex align="center" justify="center">
                <Spin indicator={<LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 48 }} spin />} />
            </Flex>
        );

    const liker = data?.article?.favorited ? (
        <span className={`${styleArticleFull.heart} ${styleArticleFull.heart_on}`} onClick={deleteLike}></span>
    ) : (
        <span className={styleArticleFull.heart} onClick={addLike}></span>
    );

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styleArticleFull.articleFullContainer}>
                <div className={styleArticleFull.articleContainer}>
                    <div className={styleArticleFull.infoContainer}>
                        <div className={styleArticleFull.infoTitleBox}>
                            <div className={styleArticleFull.titleBox}>
                                <h2 className={styleArticleFull.title}>{data?.article?.title}</h2>
                                <label className={styleArticleFull.liker}>
                                    {liker}

                                    {data?.article?.favoritesCount}
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div className={styleArticleFull.tagsBox}>
                                {data?.article?.tagList.map((item, index) => (
                                    <p className={styleArticleFull.tag} key={index}>
                                        {item}
                                    </p>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className={styleArticleFull.userInfo}>
                            <div className={styleArticleFull.userDescription}>
                                <h2 className={styleArticleFull.userName}>{data?.article?.author?.username}</h2>
                                <p className={styleArticleFull.date}>
                                    {format(new Date(data?.article?.updatedAt), "MMM d, yyyy")}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <img className={styleArticleFull.userPic} src={data?.article?.author?.image} alt="аватар" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styleArticleFull.descriptionPanel}>
                        <p className={styleArticleFull.description}>{data?.article?.description}</p>
                        {editingPanel}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Markdown className={styleArticleFull.markdown}>{data?.article.body}</Markdown>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

default Api:
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const articlesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "arcticlesApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: "https://blog-platform.kata.academy/api/",
        prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
            const token = getState()?.user?.user?.token;
            if (token) {
                headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
            }

            return headers;
        },
    }),
    getArticle: build.query({
        query: slug => `articles/${slug}`,
        providesTags: ["Article", "Articles"],
    }),
});

export const { useGetArticleQuery } = articlesApi;


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

 useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-info'));
    dispatch(signInUser(userInfo));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

Тут вспомогательные редьюсеры:
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    signInUser(state, action) {
      state.user = { ...action.payload };
    },
    logOutUser(state) {
      state.user = {};
    },
    loginStart(state) {
      state.user = { ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-info')) };
    },
  },
});

export const { signInUser, logOutUser, loginStart } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;

Такая конструкция починила всё, в локальном хранилище находятся данные авторизованного пользователя.

Это ответ на ваш вопрос?
